# List sorting method not updating order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

I'm trying to get some insight into why this sort function isn't working.

In theory, it should work the same as this: https://codepen.io/levit/pen/abmXgBR

**I have a list I'm grabbing from an API:**

```
<BookCard v-for='book in filteredBooks' :key='book.id' :book='book' />
```

**I've got a filter for search working, but my sort isn't. Here is my data with computed properties/methods:**

```
  data() {
    return {
      books: [],
      order: 1, // Ascending
      search: '',
    };
  },

computed: {
    filteredBooks() {
      return this.filterBySearch((this.sortByRating(this.books)));
    },
  },

  methods: {
    filterBySearch(books) {
      return books.filter((book) => book.volumeInfo.title
        .toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()));
    },

    sortByRating(books) {
      return books
        .sort((r1, r2) => (r2.volumeInfo.averageRating - r1.volumeInfo.averageRating)
        * this.order);
    },

    sort() {
      this.order *= -1;
    },
  },
```

**Finally, I have a button to switch the order:**

```
<button v-bind:class="order === 1 ? 'descending' : 'ascending'" @click="sort">
  Reader Rating
</button>
```

Any insight into what I might be getting wrong would be very helpful as I'm new to Vue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not pass the data property as an argument since it's available inside the methods and just sort the filtered books not the original property because the sort affects it :

```
computed: {
    filteredBooks() {
      let filtered= this.filterBySearch().slice();
      return this.sortByRating(filtered)
    },
  },

  methods: {
    filterBySearch() {
      return this.books.filter((book) => book.volumeInfo.title
        .toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()));
    },

   sortByRating(books) {
      return books.sort((r1, r2) => {
        if (
          typeof r2.volumeInfo.averageRating === "number" &&
          typeof r1.volumeInfo.averageRating === "number"
        ) {
          return (
            (r2.volumeInfo.averageRating - r1.volumeInfo.averageRating) *
            this.order
          );
        } else {
          return this.order * -1;
        }
      });
    },

    sort() {
      this.order *= -1;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my code, however, for some reason, the actual order of the list items still doesn't seem to update. Hmm...This did also stop my search filter from working too though

Comment: could you give an example in order to debug it

Comment: My bad, the search is working, but the sort still doesn't update

Comment: good, try out to import it in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wilson-ly4oz

Comment: Oh that's weird, it seems to have imported an old version, please bear with me

Comment: Here is the updated version - https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-pine-lr6j5 - the old one didn't have the sorting option yet. So the search is working and updating, but the sorting option is not updating. Sorry about that

Comment: It's the "rating" I can't seem to get updating, to clarify

Comment: I've noticed that actually, some of them are updating in the DOM and some aren't. Do you think this is due to not all of them having an "averageRating" property? Would I need to write a conditional for that?

Comment: the issue happens because `unrated` value is not a number for example `4.5-"unrated"` return `NaN` which breaks the sorting, please check my edited answer